# React Native ART library documentation

Tags: react-native

Does anyone have a clue where to find the documentation? I saw a number of components using this library but strangely couldn't find the documentation?

Comment: I'm sorry, this question is in no way off topic. It's 2020 and I'm struggling to find a documentation. Recently React Native Lean Core proposal removed the ART library in a standalone project. Somewhere buried in the project you can stumble upon [art/docs/api.md](https://github.com/react-native-community/art/blob/master/docs/api.md). It took me 3 hrs of research to find this link

Answer (score 6):

React Native ART is a RN version of React ART, which is itself a React implementation of the ART library. And the latter has some docs:

http://sebmarkbage.github.io/art/

They're not exhaustive but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: this is the correct answer at present

Comment: I am facing an issue while trying to use `Transform` as shown in the documentation, here is the link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792445/react-art-text-rotation). I am using Typescript and I get the following error: Property 'Transform' does not exist on type 'ARTStatic'

Answer (score 5):

Facebook's response to this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4789 is that the library is good to go for production but sadly there isn't any documentation for it :(

Comment: The discussion on the issue ends with a link to a user created repo with unofficial docs to RN ART. Here it is: https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md