# React Art <Text /> rotation

Tags: react-native

How can I rotate a `<Text />` from [React ART](https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md)? 
`<Text />` is a `<Shape />` based on text content using native text rendering, and so, I should be able to use `transform={ ??? }` inside it. I did not find any examples with rotation.

What should I add so I can rotate this `<Text />` bellow ?

```
import { ART } from 'react-native';
const { Text } = ART;

<Text x={0} y={0}
      font={`25px "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial`}
      fill={'red'}
      alignment={'center'}>
          Random Text that needs rotation
</Text>
```

Adding `style={{ transform: '[{ rotate: "45deg"}]' }}` is not supported, I get the following error:

> Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode;
>   }> & Readonly'.

Because I am using the `<Text \>` from React ART and **NOT** the clasic one from `react-native`

Comment: Looks like a you can use canvas context in react native. There you can apply various transformations on top of any text or image element you desire. With Canvas 2D or 3D context you can achieve almost any kind of transformation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-canvas

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can rotate and transform `ART` `Text` with `ART` Transform.

```
import { ART } from 'react-native';

const { Text, Transform } = ART;

const rotate = new Transform().rotate(45) // rotate
const rotateAndMove = new Transform().rotate(45).translate(10, 20) // x,y

<Text x={0} y={0}
  transform={rotate} 
  font={`25px "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial`}
  fill={'red'}
  alignment={'center'}>
      Random Text that needs rotation
</Text>

<Text x={0} y={0}
  transform={rotateAndMove} 
  font={`25px "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial`}
  fill={'red'}
  alignment={'center'}>
     Rotated and moved x=10 y=20
</Text>
```

Comment: Will look into it, at first attempt I did not manage to use this because I am using typescript and there is no `Transform` in `ART` only: `ClippingRectangle; Group; Shape; Surface and Text.`

Comment: With typescript Transform not shows in ART, but you can just import it and use.

Comment: Tried `import { ART } from 'react-native'; 'const { Transform } = ART;' and I still get the same error as in previous comment 'Property 'Transform' does not exist on type 'ARTStatic''